# fileExistsAtPath and checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError both didn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager, file-exists

`fileExistsAtPath` and `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` both returns `NO` Even the file exists at `server URL`

I have a file in (local)server in
   `http://10.0.0.15/images/hibrise.png`

```
  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.0.15/images/hibrise.png"];

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]];
 NSLog(fileExists ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

I have checked the file permissions also its fine.
When I type the same url in my browser it presents the image

'fileExistsAtPath' This method is used to check the file availability in internal file system

**`checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError`** This is also only for the internal iOS File System `This method is currently applicable only to URLs for file system resources. For other URL types, NO is returned` **Apple says the same for `fileExistsAtPath`**

**What is the best way to check file availability using URL**

Comment: it's Better to save the url in to NSCache and check that it found in to NScache or not. becouse You cannot check file url with NSFileManager

Answer (score 0):

`NSFileManager` is for internal iOS file system. You can not check if remote file is exist or not using `NSFileMAnager`.

Use the method `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` of class `NSURL` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but This is also only for the internal iOS File System `This method is currently applicable only to URLs for file system resources. For other URL types, NO is returned`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check a file in a location other than the device using the `NSFileManager` class.

<strike>What you need to use is NSURL method `- (BOOL)checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:(NSError **)error`</strike>

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.0.15/images/hibrise.png"];
NSError *err;
BOOL fileExists = [url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err];
```

If there was an error, it will be passed to the NSError pointer so you should also check this

Correct answer is to actually perform an HTTP HEAD request and check for a 404 error:

```
BOOL fileExists;
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.0.15/images/hibrise.png"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *headRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];
    [headRequest setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:headRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               fileExists = ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]!=404)
                           }];
```

Comment: This is cann't help for this question. From apple's doc : `This method is currently applicable only to URLs for file system resources. For other URL types, NO is returned `

Comment: Thanks! The updated answer was what I needed. In my case I was getting a 403 status code (not 404) on fails for AWS S3 files. I changed the check to statusCode == 200.